# Responder callback methods

Tags: actionscript-3, netconnection

I need to create a `Responder` object, the constructor **[documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Responder.html)** says:

> ***Parameters***
>
> **result**:*Function* — The function invoked if the call to the
>   server succeeds and returns a result.
>
> **status**:*Function* (default = null) — The function invoked if the server returns an error.

What is the parameter of the status function? it says the signature is `function(default = null)`, but it doesn't actually explain what is `default`.

- What type is `default`?
- What might it contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `function(default = null)` means that the default value for the second parameter is `null` rather than the signature if the `status` handler.

As for the signature of the `status` handler it depends on your client<->server protocol. For example look at the [`MessageResponder`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/messaging/MessageResponder.html) class that inherits the `Responder` that are used in the flex remoting. It has the strongly typing serialization of AMF directly to the [`IMessage`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/messaging/messages/IMessage.html):

```
public function MessageResponder(agent:MessageAgent, message:IMessage,
                                                    channel:Channel = null)
{
    super(result, status);

    ...      
}
...
final public function result(message:IMessage):void {...}
final public function status(message:IMessage):void {...}
```

In general you can pass the functions with the single `Object` argument:

```
public function status(message:Object):void {}
public function result(message:Object):void {}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I see now that `Function(default = null)` is not what I thought :)